# Simple Client-Server Communication?

Tags: java, sockets

Working on a server-socket lab in Java and our instructor provided us with the Client Side of the code. In the project, Client sends a string to the server. The Server then turns around and sends the string back to the client.

Client

```
        Socket server = new Socket(host, 30000); 

        // Sends the string to the Server
        Socket server = new Socket(host, 30000);
        OutputStream serverOut = server.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter serverWrite = new PrintWriter(serverOut, true);
        serverWrite.println("Bryce");


        //Manages Server's response of "Hello, Bryce!"
        InputStream serverIn = server.getInputStream();
        Scanner serverScan = new Scanner(serverIn);
        serverScan.useDelimiter("$");
        String resp = serverScan.next();
```

Server

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(30000);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();


     // Gets Message from Client
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader readerBuff = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String stringFromClient = readerBuff.readLine();


     // Sends Message back to Client
     OutputStream oos = s.getOutputStream();
     PrintWriter pl = new PrintWriter(oos, true);
     pl.println("Hello, " + stringFromClient + "!");
```

EverytimeI run the program, it pulls up a NoSuchElementException and cites the offending line in Client:

```
String resp = serverScan.next();
```

This should be a fairly simple problem(I've completed this sort of problem before). If i replace

```
 String resp = serverScan.next();
```

with

```
 String resp = serverScan.toString();
```

it works fine, but as I'm not allowed to modify the Client-Code, I'm totally confused. Am I missing something here?

Comment: serverScan.next() gets the next line from the client. serverScan.toString() gets a textual representation of the Scanner object (probably something like `java.util.Scanner@0xF35AB395`

Answer (score 0):

In the client side code, you have

```
serverScan.useDelimiter("$");
```

This means the client side scanner will use `$` as the delimiter for the incoming characters. So in order to let client side know that a complete tokenized string is sent, you need to add one more character at the end of the message string sent by server:

```
pl.println("Hello, " + stringFromClient + "!" + "$");
```

The javadoc of [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method in `Scanner` class says:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern.

Comment: I ended up adding oos.flush and oos.close to the end of my server-code and that fixed it.

Comment: @user2453973 close() implies flush(). You don't need flush().